# Retrieving Specific data on click with ionic and firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently in the process of trying to learn the ionic framework and Firebase using AngularFire.

Right now I'm trying to work on a simple(or so I thought) contacts application with multiple user accounts. The app would then display that users contacts in a list. Upon clicking on one of the contacts in the list the data for that contact (name,address,phone etc) would be displayed in a modal or other page.

I am able to display a list of contacts based on the uid from the logged-in user, the problem is how do I rerieve the data for that individual contact and display it on screen?

Here is my code so far:

This is the ion-list that holds the contacts retrieved from the items factory.

```
 <ion-list option-buttons="itemButtons" can-swipe="true"  class="item-remove-animate"  show-delete="data.showDelete" show-reorder="data.showReorder">
  <ion-item class="item-divider">Contacts(from fire):</ion-item>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" id="contactItem" ng-click="clickContact(); getAllContacts()">{{item.contactName}}

    <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="onItemDelete(item)"> </ion-delete-button>

    <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="edit(item)">Edit </ion-option-button>

    <ion-option-button class="button-calm" ng-click="share(item)">Share</ion-option-button>

    <ion-reorder-button class="ion-navicon" on-reorder="moveItem(item, $fromIndex, $toIndex)"></ion-reorder-button>

  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

This is the items factory (I removed the firebase database name and replaced it with *****)

```
 .factory("items", function($firebaseArray) {// factory for getting contact items
   var userContacts=currentU.uid;// grab current user
   var itemsRef = new     Firebase("https://******.firebaseio.com/users/"+userContacts+"/contacts");
    return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
  })
```

Here is the controller for when the user clicks on an individual contact. It currently doesn't do much besides open an empty modal.

```
$scope.clickContact = function(){// function when clicking on single contact for single contact view
      $scope.oModal2.show();// show/open contact modal when clicked on single contact };
```

Lastly here is an example of the Firebase structure.In the future their will be more information for each contact.

```
 users{
     63efb2b1-9b39-4cdb-9d57-b721e45f97c4{ //user id key
     contacts{
     -K8q4YOETVNh_LujTZD7 { //key for that specific contact
      contactName: "first contact"
      }
     -K8qE2LjUMK9IOd1OXQQ{ //key for that specific contact
     contactName: "second contact" 
     }
      }
     }
    }
```

I have tried researching this but haven't quite found the answers I'm looking for, maybe I'm not asking the right questions.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Are you trying to get all contacts for a user? or one specific contact of a user?

Answer (score 1):

To find a specific contact of a user you can do

```
var refUserContacts = new Firebase("https://******.firebaseio.com/users/"+userContacts+"/contacts");

refUserContacts.orderByChild("contactName").equalTo("first contact").on("value", function(data){
   console.log(data.val());
});
```

This will give you the contact you need. You should consider adding indexon contactName for better query performance.